# Verifying the contents in error message

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I am using org.jnuit.Assert class for unit testing my business logic.

My business logic throws an exception if particular situation occurs in runtime e.g. a particular variable should have non-zero value.

In my catch block, i want to verify this string message: "Variable var1 should have non-zero value".

I thought the following code snippet will work,

```
try{
   //business logic
}catch(Exception e) {
   CharSequence charseq = "Variable var1 should have a non-zero value";
   Assert.assertEquals("Variable var1 should have a non-zero value",true,e.getMessage().contains(charseq));
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestion, how can i achieve this?

Thanks,
Vijay Bhore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is sufficient to assert that an exception is thrown, why assert that the message contains a string you know it will?  You can do this in Junit like so:

```
@Test(expected=MyException.class)
public void test() {}
```

Your code should work as-is though. If you use Matchers you will get a better indication of why your exception isn't containing your message:

```
Assert.assertThat(e.getMessage, contains("Variable var1...");
```